Can't serve static files in Django but can serve from media
Django is v5.1
Have this settings.py:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'medialibrary.apps.MedialibraryConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig',
    'photos.apps.PhotosConfig',
    'drawings.apps.DrawingsConfig',
    'content.apps.ContentConfig',
    'app.apps.AppConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'strawberry_django',
    'imagefield',
    'mdeditor',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
]

This urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql', include('api.urls')),
    path('mdeditor/', include('mdeditor.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('admin:index'))),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

This overridden admin/base.html:
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}

This structure:

And it's not serve static files from static folder. Just shows 404. But serving static files from media folder.
I have absolutely no idea where the error can be found here.
I tried to create a completely clean new project and did the same settings with STATIC without modifying urls.py, and the result is the same - favicon.ico from the static folder is not served.

You don't really need to add urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) to urls.py
Verify if django.contrib.staticfiles is present in installed apps and you're running it with DEBUG=True. It must serve Static files with these settings
Read more

I have the django.contrib.staticfiles module in the added ones. But whether I add static() or remove it, nothing changes.
And yes, DEBUG is set to True 100%. MEDIA is served.

I have updated my question to include which INSTALLED_APPS I have.

I created a completely clean new project and did the same settings with STATIC without modifying urls.py, and the result is the same - favicon.ico from the static folder is not served.

@wokalek, as pointed by another answer also add STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] to your settings.py

added. Now I have error: «ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.»

Have you tried checking this before recommending it?

@wokalek, checked what? And Staticfiles_dirs are the dirs where your static files RESIDE and STATIC_ROOT is the place your static files will reside when you run collectstatic for PRODUCTION. Please go through the documentation once

I created a folder staticfiles and placed the favicon.ico file there.
Now it serve with this settings:
settings (add STATICFILES_DIRS for staticfiles):
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]

urls (remove static for STATIC_URL):
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

overridden admin/base.html (nothing changed):
{% block extrahead %}
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" />
{% endblock %}

And having working collectstatic command.

Change your static file serving code in settings.py file to this one.
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")


STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)


I created a directory staticfiles, put favicon.ico inside and it is not served on request /staticfiles/favicon.ico. The answer is incorrect.

You don't have to create staticfiles directory, favicon.ico inside static folder with the above line of code will work.

if you use django.contrib.staticfile, use staticfiles dir instead static root in debug.
And pay attention to the order.
will work.
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('graphql', include('api.urls')),
    path('mdeditor/', include('mdeditor.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [path('', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('admin:index'))),]


Have 404: «The current path, staticfiles/favicon.ico, didn’t match any of these.»

And why are you using STATIC_ROOT in urls.py if you commented it out?

Because an error occurs. Check what has changed.

Now it serve. But now I cant run command collectstatic, because it depends on STATIC_ROOT which is still empty. And the position of the redirect from the main page to the admin panel does not affect anything, why did you change it?

So I need create another folder for my static files like "staticfiles" folder and place here my static files. But yesterday it didn't work with the same settings. I'm surprised and don't understand why.

STATICFILES_DIRS is only used in the debug environment, and STATIC_ROOT is used in the deployment environment.
